# Uno platform: MapControl in not UWP projects

Tags: c#, android, bing-maps, uno, uwp-maps

I have a quite big project developed in UWP, and I'm thinking of migrate to Uno Platform with Android, iOS and MacOS users in mind. The biggest and most important part of the project is a MapControl, but I don't know if when migrating the project, in Android, and other OS, the app will continue using BingMaps (with all the tools and things that brings) or will use OS default map provider and engine.

Will be possible to achieve something like that with Uno on other OS that is not Windows?

[image: MapCOntrol in 3D]

Comment: Bing Maps will support Linux.  See : https://www.nuget.org/packages/ThinkGeo.MapSuite.Layers.BingMaps/

Comment: @jdweng But, will it able to do what I have asked before? BingMaps shows terrain and overlays in 3d.

Comment: The API is a text interface and doesn't have to display a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct support for Uno to use the UWP map control isn't available yet, but there are Native Android and iOS versions of the Bing maps SDK available which may be able to be called from Uno.
Here's the SDK getting started page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/mobile

Comment: This is what I was asking for. Thank you as always, Duncan!